# Raphael.js: how to let all overlapping items handle events

Tags: raphael

Say I have a small red rectangle on top of a bigger blue rectangle:

```
var paper = Raphael(0,0,500,500);

var rect1 = paper.rect(0, 0, 100, 100);
rect1.attr({fill: 'blue'});
rect1.click(greet);

var rect2 = paper.rect(10, 10, 50, 50);
rect2.attr({fill: 'red'});



var greet = function(){
    alert('hi');
};
```

How can I make the blue rectangle handle the event as well when the red rectangle is clicked?

Comment: I'm not sure if this is possible (I may well be wrong though). Is there a larger context, as I wonder if there's an alternative workaround (you could take the event point and check if insider other elements, but its kind of a clunky solution) ?

Comment: I am drawing something decorative on top of something that handle events. Perhaps, I can use canvas instead if there is no good solution.

Comment: If you can keep a hierarchy of overlapping containers/objects that may work, but I don't think separate objects will.